# Select three tables concat first with second and lastly concat all three tables

Tags: mysql

**I have three tables Province_Table, City_table and Town_table I want to select them like:**

---

I use this

```
SELECT p.province_id,p.province_name,c.city_id,t.town_id,
       Group_concat(c.city_name) city_name, 
       Group_concat(t.town_name) town_ name
FROM province_tbl p
         left JOIN city_tbl c 
               ON c.province_id = p.province_id 
         left JOIN town_tbl t
               ON t.town_id = c.town_id 
GROUP BY p.province_name,c.city_name,t.town_name order by p.province_name asc
```

Its working but output is :

```
Province Name, City Name, Town Name
```

**I want below output:**

```
Province Name   
Province Name, City Name    
Province Name, City Name, Town Name
```

See this example also [zoopla.co.uk](http://zoopla.co.uk) 
Type London into the search bar. 
Open a dropdown result that I need. Like below.

```
London 
London Blackfriars Station
London Blackfriars Station 2
London Blackfriars Station, Block 1
London Blackfriars Station, Block 2 
London Blackfriars Station, Block 3
```

*Please answer in detail because I am new in MySql.*

Comment: Can you provide sample output using real data?

Comment: can you make SQLfiddle

Comment: Province Name </br>
Province Name, City Name </br>
Province Name, City Name, Town Name

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `WITH ROLLUP` at the end of your `GROUP BY` clause - like so:

...

```
GROUP BY p.province_name,c.city_name,t.town_name WITH ROLLUP
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/1b240/5).

If you want to change the default sort order, you will need to treat the whole query as a subquery, and sort by the relevant columns in the outer query.

Comment: Not working giving this error 
#1221 - Incorrect usage of CUBE/ROLLUP

Comment: [Click here](http://www.zoopla.co.uk/) to see the example that i want. After opening the site type London at the search engine. You will see dropdown result that i want.